# pandas: float_format and decimal sign not working properly

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, decimal-point

I am trying to write a pandas DataFrame `df` to a csv-file using pandas' [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method with the following line:

```
df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False, decimal=',', sep=' ', float_format='%.3f')
```

Which gives a csv-file like the following:

```
295.998 292.500 293.000 293.000
295.998 292.500 293.000 293.000
295.998 292.500 293.000 293.000
```

So the `float_format` option works pretty well, as all numbers have three decimal digits. However, the `decimal` option (`decimal = ','`) does not seem to work, since the decimal sign is a dot and not a comma.

What I am interested is something like the following:

```
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
```

How can I convience pandas to use three decimal digits and the desired comma as decimal sign?

Comment: What's your version of pandas?

Comment: What version pandas are you using? this works fine in `0.16.2`

Comment: My version is 0.15.2 (output of `pd.__version__`)

Comment: Can you try upgrading as this is probably a bug in your version

Comment: @EdChum: How could I do this using pip (python3) on Mac OS?

Comment: I think so but I don't own a mac so can't say for sure but I think this will fix your issue

Comment: After updating pandas (`sudo pip3 install -U pandas`) everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is probably a bug in pandas version 0.15.2 since it works fine after updating to version 0.16.2 using the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install -U pandas
```

Which could be checked by

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Giving

```
'0.16.2'
```

By using the commands provided in the question the resulting csv-file looks as desired:

```
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
295,998 292,500 293,000 293,000
```

Comment: Just a note: it was not a bug, but the `decimal` option was only introduced for `to_csv` in pandas 0.16 (that it didn't raise on an unknown argument before could be considered as a bug .. :-))

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running pandas version "0.17.1". I found out that I didn't specify the dtype of the DataFrame beforehand and it ended up as type object (df.dtypes). Dataframes of type objects seem not be converted correctly as the following minimal example shows:

```
df_object = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], 'b':[2.1, 2.2, 2.3],}, dtype=object)
df_object.to_csv(decimal=',')
```

',a,b\n0,1.1,2.1\n1,1.2,2.2\n2,1.3,2.3\n'

```
df_float = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], 'b':[2.1, 2.2, 2.3],}, dtype=float)
df_float.to_csv(decimal=',')
```

',a,b\n0,"1,1","2,1"\n1,"1,2","2,2"\n2,"1,3","2,3"\n'